# Java Eclipse auto build workspace not stoping?

Tags: android, eclipse, build, workspace

I am having some problem with Eclipse auto build workspace.

That build starts, but don't it seems to be caught in an infinite loop that I cannot stop.

I'm using android platform ADT and OpenCV.
What can i do to stop it?

Answer (score 1):

Menu `Project`>`Build Automatically` uncheck